# Get current week from Access Date/Time Field in QT?

Tags: sql, qt, ms-access

I need to get from Access DataBase all items with dates during the current week. The first day of week is Monday. But i can't write any DatePart query. Last attempt was:

```
qModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM TimeTable WHERE (DatePart(\"ww\",[PlayDate])=DatePart(\"ww\",Date()));");
```

Qt returns -3010 mistake:"[Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Too few parameters. Expected 1."
Also i know that other similar queries with Year() or #SomeDate# is working.

So how can i get current week items?

Comment: What happens when you paste that query string into MS Access query design window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes in the SQL statement.

```vb
qModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM TimeTable WHERE DatePart('ww',[PlayDate])=DatePart('ww',Date());");
```

Assuming that change eliminated the error, next add the option to indicate which is the first day of your weeks.

```vb
qModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM TimeTable WHERE DatePart('ww',[PlayDate],2)=DatePart('ww',Date(),2);");
```